# Prevent tinymce autoformatting

Tags: javascript, tinymce-4

I have some troubles with tinymce. My html code is given below

```
                <div class="columns home-page-image-block" id="box-c-wrap">
                    <a href="/category/skeletons"><img src="/img/content/home-image-3.png" alt=""/></a>
                    <a href="/category/skeletons" class="home-page-image-block-title-3 image-title">
                        <span>Catalog of:</span>
                        <h4>Fossils</h4>
                    </a>
                </div>
```

and after inserting into editor I get this in "View source"

```
<div id="box-c-wrap" class="columns home-page-image-block">
<a href="/category/skeletons">
<img src="/img/content/home-image-3.png" alt="" />
</a> 
<a class="home-page-image-block-title-3 image-title" href="/category/skeletons">Catalog of:</a>
<h4>Fossils</h4>
</div>
```

The tinymce formats the code and changes it's structure by itself... How can I disable this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TinyMCE's auto-formatting is a pain.
There is no option to stop it from doing so.
Not switching from Text to Visual Editor helps.

In wordpress there's TinyMCE Advanced, which removes some of the autoformatting options, but its far from perfect.

For your backend better try using CKEditor and add this to config.js:

```
CKEDITOR.config.allowedContent = true
```

Comment: Sorry, but I need only tinymce as system which I develop uses EXTjs and transitional plugin for tinymce, Im not sure that I can find something like that for CKEDITOR...

Comment: @Oleg Patrushev - I know its been quite sometime but were you able to get around this issue ?